# Where does the 'Untagged' tag come from?

Tags: support, tags

Why are there so many questions with the [untagged](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag?

And how does it get there in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

The [untagged](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag comes from one of two events:

1. - A migrated question that does not have the tags on the migrated site (if we do not have a  [star-trek](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag when a Star Trek question gets migrated to us) then the question is auto-tagged with [untagged](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).
2. - If a tag is used only on one question for 6 months, where this tag is the only tag to the question.  The system will auto-delete the tag and re-tag the question with [untagged](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).  This does **not** bump the question.  The way to avoid this is to have more than 1 tag on the question.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.